# JSON variable substitution placeholders

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm looking for a Java library that can do variable substitution when marshaling Json to an Object on-the-fly.

For example, the Json template would have variable substitution sites/placeholders like:

```
{
  "User": {
    "Name": "${name}",
    "Age": ${age}
  }
}
```

that would result in the Java Object representing the following once marshaled:

```
{
  "User": {
    "Name": "Elvis",
    "Age": 80
  }
}
```

What I want is something along the lines of this:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
User user = mapper.readValue(new File("c:\\user.json.template"), User.class, "Elvis", 80);
```

Comment: https://github.com/typesafehub/config ??

Comment: you could also use a simple object-mapping library, that would give you that format from a class like `class User {String name; int age}`

Comment: I don't understand why do you need this. You can simply write User user = new User("Elvis", 80), or new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(new User("Elvis", 80)) to get json. You can't define class User from the template.

Answer (score 1):

This is really out of scope for JSON libraries, since JSON format itself has no support or notion of variable substitution. Your best bet may be to use a JSON library (like Jackson) to get a tree representation (for Jackson that would be `JsonNode`), then traverse it, and use another library for handling textual substitution. There are many that can do that, from `stringtemplate` to others (perhaps `MessageFormat` that other answer refers to).

It may also be possible to revert the other, if your substitutions will never funny "funny characters" (quotes, linefeeds); if so, you could use string templating lib first, JSON parser next feeding processed text.
But it is bit riskier, as usually there is eventually one case where you do end up trying to add a quote, say, and then parsing fails.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a template engine such as [Apache Velocity](https://velocity.apache.org/engine/) to preprocess the input stream, and then parse the result with a JSON parser. To make the process "on-the-fly", you can run Velocity in a separate thread, and let it write it's output to a `PipedOutputStream`.

Answer (score -1):

May be the MessageFormat object from apache commons could help ?
Here is an example : http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/text/messageformat/java-messageformat-example/

Comment: Your answer has been flagged for quality reasons. SO discourages link only answers. Please read [asnwer].